# Remove/Reduce size of docker layers used for installing a software

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-buildkit, docker-layer

**Can somebody help me?**
Sorry for the long question but I'm trying to describe my issue in as much detail as possible.
I'm trying to have a software that installed in my docker image.

- In the below image, at number 2, you can see I `COPY ace/ /tmp/` -  `ace/` is a directory that contains my software installer. In the dockerfile, I already remove /tmp/ folder after the installation has been completed.
  The question is **How can I reduce the size of the layer** used for `COPY` the installer from docker context to `/tmp/`.
- Meanwhile, you can see, at number 1, something similar with number 2, but it's size has been reduced, the actual size of `repo/` is 1 Gb. I don't know **what is the difference** here

[image: Info about layers]

My dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3.6 python3-venv  
COPY ace/ /tmp/
RUN /bin/bash -c ' \
    Some commands to install ace from /tmp/ such as: apt install -y /tmp/*.deb;
    rm -r /tmp/*'
COPY repo/ /tmp/
RUN /bin/bash -c ' \
    Some commands to install environment from /tmp/ such as: /tmp/setup_venv.sh;
    rm -r /tmp/*'
```

Comment: I can't really see what's going on in that image.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], with a sample Dockerfile you're trying to optimize, as text and not an image?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my question.  You can look at number 2 in the image, I want to remove this layer, or at least reduce the size of this.